# How to use Yolo Darknet in C++ applications?

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection, c++

I am unfortunately very inexperienced with C++ and have only used darknet in Python so far. For the work I have to set up a C++ project with Visual Studio, in which Yolov3 recognizes objects in the stream of the webcam. I use Windows and for testing purposes the whole thing should run on the CPU. Unfortunately I don't understand how I can use this repo https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet to integrate Yolov3 into my main.cpp.

Unfortunately I can't find a good starting point on the internet that explains how I can integrate the whole thing into Visual Studio (with headers, libs, includes). I have installed Cuda, Cudnn and Opencv and can also build different .sln from the repo, but I don't understand the sense or principle behind it.

The only thing I could get running was using the OpenCV DNN lib, like in this tutorial https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-object-detection-using-yolov3-with-opencv-python-c/. But I want to directly include the sourcecode like include "darknet.h" etc. to be more flexibel.

Can someone give me a starting point or an explanation of how to proceed? Any Tip  is helpful;)

Thanks!